# How do I place it like shared/folder1/newtext.txt on NAS?

Tags: xamarin, smb, nas

I would like to read/write files to/from NAS in Xamarin.Android.

https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary/blob/master/ClientExamples.md
I used SMBLibrary here and was able to implement the functionality I wanted to do itself, but was unable to place the files as shown in the title.
The current configuration is like shared/newtext.txt, but I would like to make it like shared/folder1/newtext.txt.

It was not possible to write "shared¥¥folder" in the shareName argument of client.TreeConnect().

CreateFile() also did not work even if I wrote "folder1¥newtext.txt" in the path argument.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

```
  var client = new SMB2Client();
            bool isConnected = client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IPADDRESS), SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport);
            if (isConnected)
            {
                NTStatus status = client.Login(String.Empty, ID, PASSWORD);
                ISMBFileStore fileStore = client.TreeConnect(TANAFOLDER, out status);
                object fileHandle;
                FileStatus fileStatus;
                string filePath = filename;
                if (fileStore is SMB2Client)
                {
                    filePath = @"\\" + filePath;
                }


                status = fileStore.CreateFile(out fileHandle, out fileStatus, filePath, AccessMask.GENERIC_READ | AccessMask.SYNCHRONIZE, FileAttributes.Normal, ShareAccess.Read, CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN, CreateOptions.FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | CreateOptions.FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT, null);'
```

Comment: Where is your code?  Do you get an error or exception?  Have you tried without using special characters?

Comment: I've added the code and I hope you'll take a look at it. In the case of this code, it refers to the path of the file directly under the folder specified by TreeConnect, and NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS will come back, so you can proceed with the process successfully. If you write @"\\folder1\"+filepath in filepath here, it will return NTStatus.INVAILD_PARAMETER, so you can't process it properly after that. I would like to know how to include the folder between the shared folder and the file I need in the path.